# How can I slide multiple variables by pipe in while (bash)?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I'm using bash to download file and auto change file name via wget, but when I use `|` (it's `space pipe space`) to distinguish the variables, it always read the first part of filename with space

Here is my script, I use `while read -r fileName ' | ' url` to read my download.list file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

IFS=' | '    

while read -r fileName url
do
    wget $url -O $fileName
done < download.list

exit 0
```

here is example text in my download.list
`MR HH GD | https://example/xxxx.zip`
I expect I will get `MR HH GD.zip`, but it actually give me this:
`ME.zip`

Comment: What do you mean by *"slide"*?

Comment: @tripleee Sorry, I have change the word to `distinguish`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you got past the read command. In section "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" of bash(1), the read command is defined as accepting variable names as arguments, not plain text.

You can use `IFS` like so, but you'll have to remove any unwanted whitespace yourself.

```
while IFS='|' read -r fileName url
do
    echo ">$fileName<"
    echo ">$url<"
done < download.list
```

`MR HH GD | https://example/xxxx.zip` in your download.list will output

```
>MR HH GD <
> https://example/xxxx.zip<
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I've used `wget $url -O "$fileName"` and it successfully saved file with `Test For Sapce.zip` name !

Comment: @User123 is it better write `IFS` in `while` than write it out of `while`? I'm a newbie for bash, so I don;\'t know about it..

Comment: Setting `IFS` along with the read command will set it only for that command--the new value won't persist. That is actually ideal, because you can assume the default behavior of further ahead.

Comment: @JamesR. thanks bro~ great answer for me to understand